# Lucene.Net creates empty index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene.Net + SimpleLucene in my asp .net mvc application. There is a problem with creating index from the database. The index seem to start being created well, but all i get is 5 files with sizes of 0 and 1 KB:

```
_0.fdt             0KB  
_0.fdx             0KB  
segment.gen        1KB  
segments_1         1KB  
write.lock         0KB
```

I have such a model from which i want to create index:

```
public class Feed : BaseEntity
{

    public virtual string Address { get; set; }

    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsExported { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime LastUpdateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FeedPost> Posts { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public virtual Filter Filter { get; set; }
}
```

I have implemented two necessary interfaces from lucene library: IIndexDefinition and IResultDefinition:

```
public class FeedIndexDefinition : IIndexDefinition<Feed>
{
    public Document Convert(Feed entity)
    {
        var document = new Document();
        document.Add(new Field("id", entity.Id.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        document.Add(new Field("description", entity.Description, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        document.Add(new Field("title", entity.Title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        return document;
    }

    public Term GetIndex(Feed entity)
    {
        return new Term("id", entity.Id.ToString());
    }
}


public class SearchResultDefinition : IResultDefinition<Feed>
{
    public Feed Convert(Document document)
    {
        Guid id = Guid.Parse(document.GetValue<String>("id"));
        var context = new UnitOfWork();
        Feed feed = context.FeedRepository.GetById(id);
        return feed;
    }
}
```

Indexing is performed this way:

```
    private static readonly UnitOfWork Context = new UnitOfWork();
    public static void IndexAllFeeds()
    {
        var indexWriter = new DirectoryIndexWriter(new DirectoryInfo(IndexPath), true);
        var feeds = Context.FeedRepository.Get().AsEnumerable();
        var indexService = new IndexService(indexWriter);
        IEnumerable<Feed> array = feeds.ToList();
        indexService.IndexWriter.IndexOptions.OptimizeIndex = true;
        indexService.IndexEntities(array, new FeedIndexDefinition());
    }
```

And here is the method that creates the query to perform the search

```
public FeedQuery Search(string keywords)
    {
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keywords))
        {
            String[] fields = {"title", "description"};
            var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(
                Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29,
                fields,
                new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29));
            Query q = parser.Parse(keywords);
            this.AddQuery(q);
        }
        return this;
    }
```

And finally here is the method in the controller which should find the results

```
private static IEnumerable<Feed> SearchUserFeeds(string keywords)
    {
        keywords = "title5 description5 title4 description4 title3 description3";
        IEnumerable<Feed> searchResults;
        var indexSearcher = new DirectoryIndexSearcher(new DirectoryInfo(LuceneHelper.IndexPath));
        using (var searchService = new SearchService(indexSearcher))
        {
            var query = new FeedQuery().Search(keywords);
            searchResults = searchService.SearchIndex(query.Query, new SearchResultDefinition()).Results;
        }
        return searchResults;
    }
```

If someone is able to point me to the problem i will appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Ok while your IndexWriter not closed or flushed.

If this is the index's stare after closing the writer - try to examine the index with 3rd party java tool named **lukeall**

Comment: But I don't have any kind of Flush() of Close() method within my indexWriter or indexService object.

Comment: Definitely it has Close() and Dispose()